Find elements in xml file with lxml find() method
I have xml files that are 1 million+ lines long. I'm able to parse them without issue with BeautifulSoup, but it can take a minute or more to do the parsing with bs4. I'm trying to use lxml to do the parsing to hopefully speed things up dramatically, but I can't get the find() method to work at all.
Ultimately I'm looking to replace this bs4 line with lxml code:
datamanagers = soup.find_all('Field', {'Name': 'DataManager'})

I simply cannot get the find() method to work. I figured I could start small and get the first element within root. An example xml file starts like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.spotfire.com/schemas/Document1.0.xsd" SchemaVersion="1.0">
    <Object Id="1">
        <Type>
        ...
        </Type>
    </Object>
</Root>

So I try:
with open(path_work + '\\' + file.stem + '\\' + 'AnalysisDocument.xml') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

tree.find('Object')
root.find('Object')
tree.find('.//Object')
root.find('.//Object')

Everything I try returns None. What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at tons of answers and they all make the find() function seem incredibly simple to use.

The sample you're showing has a default namespace of http://www.spotfire.com/schemas/Document1.0.xsd so that's probably why you're not finding Object elements.
You have (at least) two options:
First, and my preference, is you can bind that namespace uri to a prefix and use that in your xpath:
ns = {"s": "http://www.spotfire.com/schemas/Document1.0.xsd"}

root.find("./s:Object", namespaces=ns)

Second is to use Clark notation to specify the uri and name in your xpath:
root.find("./{http://www.spotfire.com/schemas/Document1.0.xsd}Object")

Also, you shouldn't have to open the file like this:
with open(path_work + '\\' + file.stem + '\\' + 'AnalysisDocument.xml') as f:

you can just use .parse() with the path instead of a file object:
tree = etree.parse(path_work + '\\' + file.stem + '\\' + 'AnalysisDocument.xml')

A couple of other notes...
If you're trying to find more than one Object element, you might want to use .findall() instead of .find() (which only finds one).
Instead of .findall() (or .find()) you can use .xpath() which returns a list similar to .findall() but has much better xpath support.
